# SQL Reporting Services 2005 - How to get current date as a ReportParameter

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, rdl

I have some working reports that must be deployed on SSRS. 
One more customization that I want to be added is to automatically select the FromDate as today - 1 month, and ToDate as today.

Specifically, I want to replace the fragment bellow with a piece that accomplish the requirements above:

```
 <ReportParameter Name="FromDate">
  <DataType>String</DataType>
  <DefaultValue>
    <Values>
      <Value>[Date].&amp;[2008-09-26T00:00:00]</Value>
    </Values>
  </DefaultValue>
  <Prompt>From Date</Prompt>
  <ValidValues>
    <DataSetReference>
      <DataSetName>FromDate2</DataSetName>
      <ValueField>ParameterValue</ValueField>
      <LabelField>ParameterCaption</LabelField>
    </DataSetReference>
  </ValidValues>
</ReportParameter>
<ReportParameter Name="ToDate">
  <DataType>String</DataType>
  <Prompt>To Date</Prompt>
  <ValidValues>
    <DataSetReference>
      <DataSetName>ToDate</DataSetName>
      <ValueField>ParameterValue</ValueField>
      <LabelField>ParameterCaption</LabelField>
    </DataSetReference>
  </ValidValues>
</ReportParameter>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace the hard-coded

```
[Date].&amp;[2008-09-26T00:00:00]
```

to formula

```
=DateAdd("m", -1, Now)
```

For "ToDate", just pass a formula that returns current date

```
=Now
```

Now the result looks something like this.

```
<ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="FromDate">
        <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
        <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
            <Value>=DateAdd("m", -1, Now)</Value>
        </Values>
        </DefaultValue>
        <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
        <Prompt>FromDate</Prompt>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="ToDate">
        <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
        <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
            <Value>=Now</Value>
        </Values>
        </DefaultValue>
        <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
        <Prompt>ToDate</Prompt>
    </ReportParameter>
</ReportParameters>
```

***[UPDATE]***
It looks like I have forgotten to paste `<ReportParameters>` correctly for *ToDate*; it's updated.
Above RDL was generated by configuring *Report Parameter*.
This is how I have configured date in GUI.

- FromDate:
  [image]
- ToDate: 
  [image]

Comment: @Sung,
It doesn't work.
Some more elements:
I'm trying to deploy the reports in a TFS instance (using the reporting services for that instance) and the actual value field looks like this:
<Value>[Date].[Date].&amp;[2008-09-26T00:00:00]</Value>

Answer (score 1):

You actually cant use the TSQL Date formats you ahve to use the .net methods:

```
=Now()

=DATEADD("m", -1, now())
```